# How to change data in combo based on other data selected in extjs 4

Tags: dynamic, extjs, load, store, reload

I am using extjs 4.0.7. I have a requirement wherein I have two combo boxes in the edit mode of a grid and I need to change the data in the second based on the value selected in the first one.

I am using MVC architecture for extjs and a java code that returns json string to populate data in the combo boxes. The code for my first combo box is:

view file:

```
items: [{
            id: 'country',
            header: 'Countries',
            field: {
                xtype: 'combo',
                store: [
                    ["USA","USA"],
                    ["India","India"],
                ],
                editable: false,
                allowBlank: false,
                listeners: {
                    select: function(combo, records, eOpts){
                        contactTypeGrid = combo.getValue();
                        myGrid.fireEvent('LoadStateOnSelect');
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            id: 'states',
            header: 'Sates',
            dataIndex: 'states',
            field: {
                xtype: 'combo',
                store: 'StateStore',
                valueField: 'stateDesc',
                displayField: 'stateText',
            }
        },  ....
    ]
```

controller:

```
LoadStateOnSelect: function(){
    contactTypeGrid = contactTypeGrid.toLowerCase();
    var stateStore = this.getStateStoreStore();
    stateStore.getProxy().url = "myURL.do";
    stateStore.getProxy().extraParams.act = contactTypeGrid;
    stateStore.load();
},
```

However, when I run this code, the data in the second store changes in the background but a Loading mask continues to appear in front due to which I cannot select any value.

How should I resolve the issue of connditional data load? Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried clearing the selected value in the combobox before reloading the store? You could try calling the `clearValue()` method on the combo.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Arun.

store.clearValue() is not a method however, I tried store.removeAll() but it does not help.

Using firebug while debugging, I noticed that when I make my first selection in the country combo and press the trigger for states, a request is fired and the values are perfectly loaded. However, when I repeat the process for the second time, no new request is fired however the data in states changes and a "Loading" mask appears. 

What could this mean?

Comment: My Bad. store.clearValue() is not a method, however, componentReference.clearValue() exists. I tried that but even that does not Help.

Comment: I tried reproducing this, but I did not have any problems when reloading  the store with new data.

Comment: I scaled down my application to create a new folder that reproduces this, however, I still have this problem. I am sure there is a mistake I am making somewhere. Can you please share a code fragment highlighting my mistake. I reproduced this scenario using a local data store eliminating the need of data from java.

Comment: do you have a link to where you are hosting this folder? I can take a look.

Comment: Oh yes, I uploaded it on FileDen. Please let me know in case you find any short comings. [link to my module named nsccFirmMembership](http://www.fileden.com/files/2012/5/3/3299804/nsccFirmMembership.zip)

Comment: Any leads? 
I have been working on this for quite some time now!

Comment: Thanks for the help though. Could you please post a fragment of code which worked smoothly for you? I'll see if I can change my application structure to that!

Answer (score 0):

I have a temporary fix for this. However, I am still looking for a solution that is more stable and workable.

Solution: 
Whenever changing the data in the dependant store you could expand the combo box which loads the new data correctly.

```
LoadStateOnSelect: function(){
    contactTypeGrid = contactTypeGrid.toLowerCase();
    var stateStore = this.getStateStoreStore();
    stateStore.getProxy().url = "myURL.do";
    stateStore.getProxy().extraParams.act = contactTypeGrid;
    statesCombo.expand(); //Here I am assuming that "statesCombo" has a 
                         //reference to the dependant combo box.
    stateStore.load(); 
},
```

This might save somebody else's time however, In case somebody finds a more viable solution, please let me know as well.

Comment: Hey Merc the .expand() works as a quick fix... Have you found a permanent fix yet?

Answer (score 0):

**carStore**- any store for main combo 
**carModelStore** - store, the content of which should be depended on selection in the carStore

Consider more general and useful example when data is getting from server.

```
var carModelStore = new Ext.data.Store({
    reader: new Ext.data.JsonReader({
        fields: ['id', 'car-model'],
        root: 'rows'
    }),
    storeId: 'car-model-store',
    proxy: new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
        url: 'carmodeldataprovider.json?car-name=lamborghini'
    }),
    autoLoad: true
});


{ xtype: 'combo', name: 'car-name', fieldLabel: 'Car', mode: 'local', store: carStore, triggerAction: 'all',
    listeners: {
        select: function(combo, records, eOpts){
            var carName = records.get('car-name');
            var carModelStore = Ext.StoreMgr.lookup("car-model-store");

            carModelStore.proxy.setUrl('carmodeldataprovider.json?car-name=' + carName, false);
            carModelStore.reload();
        }
    }

}
```